# Java: Printing ALL Args as single string

Tags: java

Ok, I want a line of code That will allow me to print all args as one string.

Example of what i need: lets say arg[0] = "Hi"; and lets say arg[1] =
"there";

i want it to print "Hi there", not something like [Hi, there] when you use
Array.toString()

Thanks - Jay (0-0)/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) the strings together and print them. Like:

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(String.join(" ",args));
    }

}
```

The first argument, the `delimiter`, is here `" "` (a string containing one space). Such that there is a space between two arguments.

Note that this program is *almost* identical to the `echo` program you see on a lot of operating systems.

Finally note that although this program does not contain a loop, the `String.join` definitely need some form of looping inside the method.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it worked.

Comment: @JayParker The [correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) way to say thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Java 8+, you can use a `Stream` and a `Collector`. Like,

```
String[] arg = { "Hi", "there" };
System.out.println(Stream.of(arg).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

which outputs (as I think you wanted)

```
Hi there
```

Comment: Someone posted the solution i needed, Thank you for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

In java 8 you can use this

```
Arrays.asList(args).forEach(x -> System.out.print(x + " "));
```

Answer (score -1):

Override the Array toString method? You'd have to use a loop in there to get the desired result though.

Comment: Someone posted the solution i needed, Thank you for the response though.